# Using Back Propagation Neural Network given continuous class labels

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am given a dataset where the class labels are continuous values between `[-1,1]`. Based on this, I have few questions:

1. Can I use Back-Propagation Neural Network (BPNN) for this problem? Previously, I had a different dataset where the labels are **binary classes** but for this dataset I am not sure since it is now a regression problem.
2. In case neural network can work with this dataset, what activation function should I use? `Sigmoid`, hyperbolic tan function (`tanh`), or rectified linear unit (`relu`)?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use [MLPRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html). And as for activation functions you can try out all these and see what works best for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Basically yes, Backpropagation works fine for both classification and regression problems.
2. At the output layer you should use tanh, as it matches the range of your output ([-1, 1]), but for hidden layers you should use ReLU or similar. Do not use sigmoid or tanh for hidden layers (only in recurrent networks) as they will produce the vanishing gradient problem